# Source of "Open in New Tab"

Tags: firefox, browser, http, website, redirection

I have a tab open and I want to know the source of this tab as I opened this tab from another tab by clicking `Open Link in New Tab` on a link.

It's especially happening and useful when reading Wikipedia articles and opening wikiLinks in other tabs to read later but as the tabs grow in amount I usually forget the source that lead me to that tab so can't make a relation.

In some cases I rely on `Back` button, when opening in the current tab, or `Redirected from...` in Wikipedia articles when the title of the article is different, to find and go back to the original source page, but it's not always happening.

[image: An odd example]

I am looking for the source, that's the name or the URL of the tab that opened the new tab in question.

I couldn't find any good information on Google about the topic and I think finding it might be somehow done through `GCLI`, `about:config`, or somewhere else in Settings as I'm on Firefox.

Comment: I use the TabMixPlus add-on, which gives you almost complete control over when and where a new tab is opened. Among its many options, you can choose to open a new tab from a link in an adjacent tab, which immediately shows where it came from. One of the reasons I don't regularly use Google Chrome is that it has nothing that comes remotely close.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the page referrer.

Open the *Web Console* in Firefox. `Ctrl+Shift+K` or `F10 > Tools > Web Developer > Web Console`. The shortcut and the key-sequence may differ according to platform you're running on. Type the `document.referrer` command into the command line at the very bottom of the console & hit enter. After that referrer will appear in the console.

You can also use *Firebug* instead of the *Web Console* if you have installed it, the *Web Console* is AFAIK shipped with Firefox by default now.

Comment: What's the main difference if any between Web Console and Firebug? Why one would need to install that add on if WC is built-in ?

Comment: Web console is now a part of Firefox Web Developer Tools. I can remember the times when there was no such thing as WDT available for Firefox and the Firebug was the only option (very good option though) for the web developers. Many of the web-devs still prefer Firebug until now. As I couldn't assume if you already use Firebug, I mentioned both options. If you don't need firebug for web development, you do not need to install it.It is possible that both tools will be merged sometimes in the future: https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/02/08/merging-firebug-into-the-built-in-firefox-developer-tools/